# Does there exist a projection (of a variety) birational onto its image and satisfying additional conditions?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X \subset \mathbb P^n$ be an irreducible (projective) variety of dimension $k < n-1$.
By Harris [Har, Lecture 18, page 224], the projection $\pi_p : \mathbb P^n - \{p\} \to \mathbb P^{n-1}$ from a general point p is birational onto its image. In fact, if we choose $q \in X$ any point, then it is enough for p to lie outside the cone $\overline{q,X}$.

My questions are:

1) Why it is enough for $p$ to lie outside $\overline{q,X}$?

2) How exactly $\overline{q,X}$ for $q \in X$ looks like?  I.e. which lines, other than
$\overline{q,r}$, $q \neq r$, it contains? I guess that tangents at $q$...

In fact, what I need is the following:
Assume that $X \subset \mathbb P^n$ is an irreducible variety of dimension $k$, $0 < k < n-1$ containing some real points (i.e. points with all coordinates real) and not lying in the infinite part of $\mathbb P^n$ (i.e. having some points with first coordinate nonzero).
Then there exists a map $\varphi : \mathbb P^n -A \to \mathbb P^{k+1}$, where $A$ is disjoint from $X$ such that:

1) $\varphi$ maps affine points to affine points (where affine means first coordinate nonzero)

2) $\varphi$ maps real points to real points

3) $\varphi(X)$ is irreducible hypersurface

4) $deg \varphi(X) = deg X.$

The natural candidate for $\varphi$ is a projection $\pi_\Lambda$, where $\Lambda$ is $(n-k-2)$-plane generated by general real points, lying in the infinite part of $\mathbb P^n$ and disjoint with $X$. This would guarantee 1)-2). Moreover, if such $\pi_\Lambda$ is birational onto its image,  then 4) follows from [Har, def. 18.1.] and 3) should also follows.
But this is only the intuition and I am missing a solid proof...

Any help is more than welcome!

[Har] J. Harris: Algebraic Geoemtry, A First Course, 1992